# Install Sitecore XC 9 Update 1 on Windows 8.1 / Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Currently I am trying to install Sitecore XC 9 Update 1 on a windows 8.1 PC and the documentation tells you that there are some problems with the installation, because of a missing support from Powershell Scripts on 8.1. But they don't tell you how to solve this problem and windows 8.1 is supported from SC.

[image]

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration: A parameter cannont be found that matches parameter name "signer".
```

someone has a good link how to install it on Windows 8.1?

do you need more Informations or Logs to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all you need to create all certificates by your own. Here its good to install sitecore on a Windows 10 so that you see which certificates you need.
- I had to use makecert when you want to create the certifiactes on your windows 8.1 oder Windows Server 2012R2
- then you need to search in your SIF config files after "DO_NOT_TRUST" and replace this string with your own prefix or with a clear string
- you need the thumbprint from your own "root" certificat and you need to replace the "DefaultValue" from "RootCertFileName" Parameter Replace the "SitecoreRootCert" with your Thumbrpint from your Root certificate
- when you have created all certificates with the right name in the right place then the installation should run without any errors. Because sitecore does not try to create any certificate because they all exist and so you get no errors from the sitecore scripts that they can't find signer and ....